# Django - How to modify the default behavior of Radio Buttons

Tags: django, django-forms

I've a ModelForm with Radio buttons that is generating an extra option(o ---------). This is the output:

```
o ---------
o Option 1
o Option 2
o Option 3
```

How can I remove the (o ---------)?

Here is my ModelForm:

```
class SomeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    sometype = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=SomeType.objects.all(), required=True, widget=forms.RadioSelect)

    class Meta:
        model = Some
```

Any clues on how to achieve this?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with an extra `empty_label=None` parameter

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield

```
sometype = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=SomeType.objects.all(), required=True, widget=forms.RadioSelect, empty_label=None)
```